# Can DLNA renderer play web URI?

Tags: upnp, dlna

I'm experimenting with DLNA, and I'm able to play local network URIs on a DLNA renderer. I have a sample app with GUI that shows available actions for a renderer, lets invoke them and see state variables.

When I feed a renderer with a local network mp3 URI it plays it OK. The URI looks like:
[http://192.168.0.132:9000/disk/DLNA-PNMP3-OP01-FLAGS01700000/O0$1$8I528.mp3](http://dummy_highlight)

But when I feed it with a web link like this one:
[http://somehost.com/p28/e8dfsf1bae84.mp3](http://dummy_highlight)

it doesn't play it (saying different things implementation dependent - can be state `PLAYING` on one renderer or state `STOPPED` on  another)

So I wonder, if there is a restriction somewhere to play non-local URIs or some other problem that prevents me using it like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is RECOMMENDED that fully qualified URLs to resources on the device are not embedded in HTML presentation pages, but that
relative URLs are used instead, so that the host portion of the embedded URLs does not need to be modified to match the
address on which the GET was received.

Answer (score 0):

dlna is local network only. that is not going to work for somehost.com.

https://superuser.com/questions/700720/dlna-server-outside-lan